# Angular kendo notifications 'https://localhost:44350/@progress/kendo-angular-notification' get request error 404

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, http-status-code-404, node-modules

Im trying to install @progress/kendo-angular-notification. when I start the app it gets stuck with a 404 error because **https://localhost:44350/@progress/kendo-angular-notification** cannot be accessed. I Found out that the issue is because the request doesn't go through the node modules, as in it should be **https://localhost:44350/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-notification.** How do I fix this.
[This is how the error is shown in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr3ec.png)
[This is how it looks like in the network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pZYd.png)
[This is a different package this is what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSbm6.png)

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular4",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation for visual studio 2017 & WebApi",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "build": "gulp build",
    "dev-build": "gulp dev-build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "5.0.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "3.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "3.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "3.4.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "3.5.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "3.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "1.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "3.1.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-notification": "^1.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^2.5.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor": "3.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "^1.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "1.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "1.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-popup-common": "1.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-schematics": "0.2.5",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "2.46.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jszip": "3.2.2",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "tslib": "^1.7.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "browserify": "^16.2.3",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-cache-bust": "1.4.0",
    "gulp-clean": "0.3.2",
    "gulp-concat": "2.6.1",
    "gulp-inline-ng2-template": "2.0.1",
    "gulp-minify": "0.0.15",
    "gulp-minify-css": "1.2.4",
    "gulp-typescript": "3.2.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "3.0.1",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "npm": "^6.14.4",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "systemjs-builder": "^0.15.16",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "3.0.3",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Tried the following.
Deleted node modules, package.json reinstalled multiple times.
Installed @progress/kendo-angular-notification globally to see if it would work.
Changed the package.json manually and reinstalled node modules.

Comment: Found out that the issue was with the path name '@progress/kendo-angular-notification': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-notification/dist/systemjs/kendo-angular-notification.js', not being included in the systemjs.config file. adding it to systemconfig map section solved the issue.